# Simplest way to deserialize JSON with restsharp?

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialization, restsharp

```
{    
    "access_token": "fooToken",
    "token_type": "fooTokenType",
    "expires_in": fooExpres,
    "refresh_token": "fooRefresj",
    "created_at": forCreatedTime,
    "user_id": fooUserID,
}
```

My web service returns the above JSON when I send a post request to it and I can get my program to write the JSON to the terminal in raw unformatted format. But I'm unsure of what would be the simplest way of deserializing it.

```
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am using the above to actually execute the request and from what I've gathered so far I would need to change that line to...

```
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute<fooClass>(request);
```

and then create a fooClass like this?

```
public class fooClass
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public int created_at { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm unsure on what extra pieces of code I would need to just get a basic program that could say write the access_token or whatever to the console?
Sorry this is my first time playing about with accessors and restSharp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use -

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<fooClass>(json);
Console.WriteLine(o.access_token);
```

You'll need to use `JSON.Net` or any `json` parsing library.